# Footer not sticking to bottom

Tags: html, css, blogs, tumblr

I'm having trouble with my footer sticking to the bottom of my blog entire pages. I run into two issues. First if I use `position:absolute` the footer rises to about the middle of the main blog page. If I leave that alone, it sticks to the bottom but rises to the middle on the blog entire pages. Footers are something I always have trouble with.

Here's my current CSS style for the footer

```
footer {
text-align: left;
background-color: #f4f4f4;
padding-top: 40px;
padding-bottom: 40px;
z-index: 1;
bottom:0;
width:100%;
}
```

Here's a link to the page http://pixelogicblog.tumblr.com/post/41025998534/tes-post

Answer (score 5):

Check out sticky footer solutions using CSS:

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

The reason your footer is only halfway down the page with `position: absolute` is that you haven't set a min-height on the body and html elements. Without that, the body only takes up as much space as you have content for it -- and then the footer is aligned with that bottom, not the bottom of the window.

Try adding this to your CSS to make it take up at least the height of the window:

```
html, body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixes the main blog footer, but I still get the middle situated footer on the entire pages. Makes sense though to allow the body and html content extend past it's intended height.

Comment: Getting a sticky footer working right (so it sticks to the bottom of the window when the content is shorter, but scrolls with the content when the content goes longer) is a bit tricky. I suggest that second approach from ryanfait. Copy the HTML structure and layout CSS from there and you should be good to go. :)

Comment: By the way, your page is misusing the `<header>` element. That element's meant for the page header only, but you're using it for the entire page that's not in the footer.

Comment: It has to do with the the Tumblr code for displaying posts. I played around with the Ryanfait's code and got the same result, with the Tumblr code...

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this?

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Cross browser (IE6+ too) and easy to understand.

Coincidentally, your current footer isn't appearing at the bottom of the page as its position is set to `relative`, set its position to `absolute` and it will be positioned at the bottom of the page (as long as the page is no longer than the viewport). Relative positioning only sets an elements position relative to where it would be normally, for example if you set `bottom: -10px` on the `footer` element, then it would appear 10 pixels lower than it would otherwise have done (hope I'm making sense there!)

If you position something absolutely, it is positioned absolutely to either the body tag, or the next nearest parent with a position set to `relative` (as I understand it anyway)

Comment: I understand what you guys are saying, but it doesn't seem to work. I have the viewpoint of the page at 100% in height and the footer position set at absolute. It should work!

Comment: you need to add a div inside the body that wraps everything with an id of `container` then give it the following rules: `min-height: 100%; position: relative;` then give your `header` element 140px bottom padding, and change `min-height` to `height` for the `html` and `body` elements

Comment: *hopefully* that should do it, I'll also take time to say that wrapping your content inside a `header` element is semantically very incorrect ... you `header` element should only contain the header of said document, you should instead probably wrap your main content in a div

Answer (score 0):

Set the position to absolute

```
position:absolute;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to note that any positioning aside from `static`(the default) takes it out of document flow. My way of getting around this is to add margin-bottom to the body content equal to the height of #Footer. Doing this ensures an empty space is always behind the footer equal to its height, preventing it from overlapping the content. Using `absolute`, and `fixed` can result to content overlapping.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to stick the footer at the bottom, you can use `min-height` with viewheight unit on the `header`, `main content` and `footer`.

Example:

```
<header style="min-height: 10vh">...</header>
<div id="main-content" style="min-height: 85vh">...</div>
<footer style="min-height: 5vh">...</footer>
```

With this, if you have don't use all your view height with your content, the footer will still stick at the bottom. This is the best way I found to stick the footer at the bottom.

I hope it will help few people.